# Read an image pixel by pixel in Ruby

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to open an image file and store a list of pixels by color in a variable/array so I can output them one by one.

Image type: Could be BMP, JPG, GIF or PNG. Any of them is fine and only one needs to be supported.
Color Output: RGB or Hex.

I've looked at a couple libraries (RMagick, Quick_Magick, Mini_Magick, etc) and they all seem like overkill. Heroku also has some sort of difficulties with ImageMagick and my tests don't run. My application is in Sinatra.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Rmagick`'s [`each_pixel`](https://rmagick.github.io/image2.html#each_pixel) method for this. `each_pixel` receives a block. For each pixel, the block is passed the pixel, the column number and the row number of the pixel. It iterates over the pixels from left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

So something like:

```
pixels = []

img.each_pixel do |pixel, c, r|
    pixels.push(pixel)
end
# pixels now contains each individual pixel of img
```

Comment: Just curious; how is the performance of Rmagick in this case?  I work on a game engine as a hobby that utilizes a ruby front end and their built in bitmap class is extremely slow in regards to pixel-by-pixel access.

Comment: The original question states that the author has looked at RMagick and determined it to be 'overkill'.

Comment: @Phogz So you downvote? Even though the OP determines it to be overkill, doesn't mean that it is. If they *really knew* what they needed, they wouldn't have asked. This answer is correct and does what's asked.

Comment: For large images, this method will probably be annoyingly slow. A quicker method would be to use `img.export_pixels_to_str` and then extract individual pixels from the resulting string.

Comment: This worked easiest for me. I did determine it as overkill earlier just assuming that there would be simpler, non-ImageMagick-based ways to access any type of image pixel. RMagick install is now a lot easier with some automated scripts (including ImageMagick install) and I've been able to access the pixels easily.

Comment: Just so ya know, RMagick's pixel object leaks memory all over the place, and can't really be cleaned up :x

Comment: what is there in img object?

Answer (score 14):

I think [Chunky PNG](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) should do it for you. It's pure ruby, reasonably lightweight, memory efficient, and provides access to pixel data as well as image metadata.

Comment: +1, Good library. This answer would be even better if you provided a code snippet that uses `Chunky PNG` to do what's asked. But, *this library is only for PNG's.* The OP specifically states the file could be more than just PNG.

Comment: @Alex I think you have misread the OP. It says that "any one of them is fine and only one needs to be supported". I interpret that to mean that the OP will use whatever one format is easiest based on the library.

Comment: Correct, supporting only PNG is fine. It mentions not needing RMagick obviously but does it still require ImageMagick support?

Comment: @AndersH If you follow the link and read the first line of the README, it says: _"This library can read and write PNG files. It is written in pure Ruby for maximum portability. Let me rephrase: it does NOT require RMagick or any other memory leaking image library."_

Comment: Chunky PNG is really great - I'd highly recommend it. Every experience I've had with RMagick has eventually lead to segfaults and other strange crashes. It aught to be a library of last resort, and I certainly would be very weary of it if needing to incorporate any user input.

Comment: @Alex suggests that this answer would be a lot better with a code snippet and I agree.
A suitable snippet can be found at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905978/alternatives-to-rmagick-imagemagick-for-reading-image-pixel-by-pixel#answer-11907718

Answer (score 2):

If you are only opening the file to display the bytes, and don't need to manipulate it as an image, then it's a simple process of opening the file like any other, reading X number of bytes, then iterating over them. Something like:

```
File.open('path/to/image.file', 'rb') do |fi|
  byte_block = fi.read(1024)
  byte_block.each_byte do |b|
    puts b.asc
  end 
end
```

That will merely output bytes as decimal. You'll want to look at the byte values and build up RGB values to determine colors, so maybe using `each_slice(3)` and reading in multiples of 3 bytes will help.

Various image formats contain differing header and trailing blocks used to store information about the image, data format and EXIF information for the capturing device, depending on the type. Probably going with a something that is uncompressed would be good if you are going to read a file and output the bytes directly, such as uncompressed TIFF. Once you've decided on that you can jump into the file to skip headers if you want, or just read those too to see or learn what's in them. Wikipedia's [Image file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats) page is a good jumping off place for more info on the various formats available.

If you only want to see the image data then one of the high-level libraries will help as they have interfaces to grab particular sections of the image. But, actually accessing the bytes isn't hard, nor is it to jump around.

If you want to learn more about the EXIF block, used to describe a lot of different vendor's Jpeg and TIFF formats [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can be handy. It's written in Perl so you can look at how the code works. The docs nicely show the header blocks and fields, and you can read/write values using the app.

I'm in the process of testing a new router so I haven't had a chance to test that code, but it should be close. I'll check it in a bit and update the answer if that didn't work.

Comment: I should clarify; format matters because the OP doesn't want header info and whatnot, just pixel data.

Comment: OP doesn't specify that headers are to be skipped. If you are assuming perhaps you can ask the OP to clarify rather than downvote.

Comment: And I quote - "I'm trying to open an image file and store a list of pixels by color in a variable/array so I can output them one by one."  Seems pretty clear.

Comment: Downvoting is how you separate the good answers from the bad/not useful answers.  This answer was wrong.  It has now been edited, but it still doesn't answer the question.  It's nothing personal.

Comment: While I understand the downvoters intention, this answer is perfectly fine for the OP's question. +1 Unless the question is clarified, this answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I agree. The OP is not clear. This could be an programming assignment or a self-assigned challenge to learn low-level access to structured files, such as images, since the high-level libraries are "overkill".

Comment: I suppose I agree with that.  I edited it to remove my downvote considering the info you added with your edit.